# Finding the distance from the origin to the surface $xy^2 z^4 = 32$ using the method of Lagrange Multipliers

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

**Problem:** Find the distance from the origin to the surface $xy^2z^4 = 32$.

**Attempt:** The Lagrange equation for this problem is $L(x,y,z, \lambda) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + \lambda (xy^2 z^4 - 32)$. Setting the first partials to zero we have \begin{align*} \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} &= 2x + \lambda y^2 z^4 = 0 \qquad (1)  \\ \frac{\partial L}{\partial y} &= 2y + 2 \lambda x y z^4 = 0 \qquad (2) \\ \frac{\partial L}{\partial z} &= 2z + 4 \lambda x y^2 z^3 = 0 \qquad (3) \\ \frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda} &= xy^2 z^4 - 32 = 0 \qquad (4)
\end{align*}
Now I'm having a hard time solving this system for $x,y$ and $z$. Here is what I did so far. From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get \begin{align*} \frac{2x}{y^2 z^4} = - \lambda \qquad \text{and} \qquad \frac{1}{xz^4} = - \lambda \end{align*} Thus $\frac{2x}{y^2 z^4}  = \frac{1}{xz^4} $ or $y^2 = 2x^2$ after simplification. Also, from $(2)$ and $(3)$ we can deduce that \begin{align*} \frac{1}{xz^4} = - \lambda = \frac{2z}{4xy^2 z^3} \end{align*} so that $2y^2 = z^2$ after simplification. Now I used all this and substituted it into $(4)$. This gave me \begin{align*} x(2x^2) (4y^4) - 32 = 0 \end{align*} or (since $y^4 = 4x^4)$ \begin{align*} 8x^3 (4x^4) - 32 = 0 \end{align*} 
This means that $32x^7 - 32 = 0$, so that $x = 1$. Then $y^2 = 2$, so that $y = \pm \sqrt{2}$. Then $z^2 = 4$, so that $z = \pm 2$. So I found the points $(x,y,z) = (1, \sqrt{2}, 2)$ and $(1, - \sqrt{2}, -2)$. They both give me the distance $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} = \sqrt{7}$, so I'm guessing they are equal? Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: I suppose that you meant *the shortest distance to the surface*. What you did is very correct to me.

Comment: I suppose that would make more sense, but this problem is from my calculus textbook, and it really just says 'distance' and not 'shortest distance'.

Comment: There are an infinitr number of distances from the origin to any surface but only one which is the shortest. Since you are asked to use Lagrange multipliers, we can bet that they missed the word *shortest*. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Conventionally I think *distance* has the connotation of *shortest distance*. Eg. The *distance* between  two sets in a metric space.

Comment: i have also $\sqrt{7}$ for $x=1,y=-\sqrt{2},z=-2$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: If I say "the distance from my house to the sea is 200 meters", I obviously mean the shortest distance. The same applies here: the distance from a point to a set is the infimum of the distances of all points in the set. This is unambiguous.

Comment: @TonyK. May be just a question of semantics ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Well, obviously $-$ we are talking about the meaning of a word. In this case, the meaning is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is correct, except the last part.  You should get four minimizing points.  (You mistakenly assumed that $y$ and $z$ must be both positive or both negative.)

However, there is a solution without using Lagrange multipliers.  Note by AM-GM that
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=x^2+2\left(\frac{y^2}{2}\right)+4\left(\frac{z^2}{4}\right)\geq 7\sqrt[7]{x^2\left(\frac{y^2}{2}\right)^2\left(\frac{z^2}{4}\right)^4}=7\sqrt[7]{\left(\frac{xy^2z^4}{32}\right)^2}=7\,.$$
The equality holds iff $x^2=\frac{y^2}{2}=\frac{z^2}{4}$, which means $(x,y,z)=\big(1,\pm\sqrt{2},\pm 2\big)$.  Hence, the required distance is $\sqrt{7}$.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility. First, 
$$\tag{$*$}
xy^2z^4 = 32 \Longrightarrow y^2 = \frac{32}{xz^4}.
$$
Notice that we can arbitrarily divide by $x,y$, or $z$ since any point with a coordinate equal to $0$ do not belong to your surface.

Now, consider the **squared** norm of a generic point $(x,y,z)$ and use $(*)$:
$$
x^2+y^2+z^2 = x^2 + \frac{32}{xz^4} + z^2 =: N(x,z).
$$
We want to minimize $N(x,z)$ over $\mathbb{R}^2$. Thus, looking for zeros of the gradient, we obtain the system
$$
\begin{cases}
0 = \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}(x,z) = 2x - \frac{32}{x^2z^4},\\
0 = \frac{\partial N}{\partial z}(x,z) = 2z - \frac{128}{xz^5},
\end{cases}
$$
that is solved by $x = 1$ and $z = \pm 2$. In particular, the minimum is $7$.

Answer (score 0):

A hint:

Multiply $(1)$ by $x$, $(2)$ by $y$, and $(3)$ by $z$ and look at the three equations you got.